# Understanding Eloquent relationships

Tags: eloquent, relational-database, laravel-5, has-many

please i really want to understand Eloquent relationships because i am having a lot headaches in this app i am building, in the show catalogue styles section, what i want to achieve is to show two images of each style **catalogue@styles** on the page, that is if two images are uploaded (front) and (back) images but by default it will show the front view, the screenshot will help you understand better

**SCREENSHOTS**

[image: catalogue styles list]

This first image shows the styles listing with a default front view, but when viewed more it should show the font and back images in a slide.

[image: catalogue style viewmore]

This image is showing a particular style clicked to view more, with the front and back images sliding.

**THE PROBLEM**

I want to be able to show the front and back images when viewed more, but it is showing a different image from a different id.

**EXISTING CODE**

```
$catalogueStyles = DB::table('catalogueimages')
->select('catalogueimages.id',
    'catalogueimages.user_id',
    'catalogueimages.catalogue_style_id',
    'catalogueimages.catalogue_style_view',
    'catalogueimages.new_name',
    'catalogueimages.image_path',
    'cataloguestyles.id',
    'cataloguestyles.user_id',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_name',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_description',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_tags',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_rating',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_publisher_name',
    'cataloguestyles.catalogue_style_publisher_url')
  ->join('cataloguestyles','cataloguestyles.id','=','catalogueimages.catalogue_style_id')
  ->where('catalogue_style_view',0)
  ->get();
```

i want to relate the **cataloguestyles** table with the **catalogueimages** table so as to combine them and pull the data from the db, i have tried this for a test

**Cataloguestyle model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Wasamar;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cataloguestyle extends Model
{
    /**
             * The database table used by the model.
             *
             * @var string
     */

    protected $table = 'cataloguestyles';

    function catalogueimage(){

            return $this>hasMany('App\Wasamar\Catalogueimage','catalogue_style_id');
    }
}
```

**Catalogueimage model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Wasamar;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Catalogueimage extends Model
{
/**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'catalogueimages';


    function cataloguestyle(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Wasamar\Cataloguestyle','id');
    }
}
```

When i try the hasMany function on the catalogue style and try to get the values, i get this error

**FatalErrorException in routes.php line 246: Call to a member function catalogueimage() on null**

Comment: You have to have a Eloquent model at first before calling its functions. You should be able to do something like this `$catalogue = Catalogue::whereId($id)->first()` and then call its function `$images = $catalogue->catalogueimage()->get()`

Comment: Maybe php declare class function private by default, try changing it to `public function cata..`

Comment: @RikardOlsson i have not set the foreign key for the field too, i just try setting it and i get this.

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `wasamar`.`#sql-12a0_a1` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `catalogueimages` add constraint `catalogueimages_catalogue_style_id_foreign` foreign key (`catalogue_style_id`) references `cataloguestyles` (`id`))**

Comment: @RikardOlsson am still getting this error `FatalErrorException in routes.php line 254:
Call to a member function catalogueimage() on null`

Comment: You don't actually need foreign key -constraints on the db for Eloquent to fetch a models relation. Maybe, if you try to explicit set the table name on each model like this `protected $table = "your-table-name"` on each model. The thing is that Eloquent by default looks for the model name + s (as in cataloguestyleS and catalogueimageS) when looking for the table. If you could edit your post and give information of all the tables, all the models and the code calling it, I maybe will be able to point out the problem more exactly

Comment: I did that **Cataloguestyle** class has a table of  `$table = 'cataloguestyles'` while **Catalogueimage** class has a table of `protected $table = 'catalogueimages'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120209/discussion-between-udeme-samuel-and-rikard-olsson).